# Show that $f(x,y)=x^2y^4+x^4y^2-3x^2y^2+1≥0 \ \forall (x,y)$

Tags: calculus

Show that $$f(x,y)=x^2y^4+x^4y^2-3x^2y^2+1≥0 \ \forall (x,y)$$

I tried finding the critical points but $\delta = (f_{12})^2-f_{11}f_{22}$

Which is the test whether the point is saddle or extremum came out to be

$\delta = 0$ which doesn't let us make any conclusions.
Any suggestions on what we should do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your objective function is symmetric under $x\mapsto-x$ and $y\mapsto -y$. Consequently you can assume without loss of generality that $x,y\geq 0$. On this domain, it is furthermore true that $x^2$, $y^2$ are in one-to-one correspondence with $x,y$ respectively. Hence we can substitute $(u,v)=(x^2,y^2)$, in terms of which the objective function is quadratic and readily minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: AM-GM inequality: $x^2y^4+x^4y^2+1\ge 3x^2y^2$

Comment: What do you mean by AM-GM ?

Comment: Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean .

Comment: Any other way would be appreciated, need something which is more satisfactory

Answer (score 0):

If you want another way, then
$$
\begin{gathered}
  x^{\,2} y^{\,2} \left( {x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  - 3} \right) + 1 \geqslant 0 \hfill \\
  r^{\,2} \left( {\cos ^{\,2} \theta \sin ^{\,2} \theta } \right)\left( {r^{\,2}  - 3} \right) + 1 \geqslant 0 \hfill \\
  \frac{{r^{\,2} }}
{4}\left( {\sin ^{\,2} \left( {2\theta } \right)} \right)\left( {r^{\,2}  - 3} \right) + 1 \geqslant 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and
$$
\min \frac{{x(x - 3)}}
{4} = \left. { - \frac{9}
{{16}}\;} \right|_{\,x = 3/2} 
$$